# Confusion around closure/scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

Today while working with some JS I had a bug in my code. I was able to resolve it but I don't really understand why the change I made works. All I can guess is that it comes down to either closure or variable scope.

I was trying to build up a nested hash of arrays like so:

```
var maxNumberOfPairs = 2;
var container = {};
var pairsHash = {};
$.each(["nurse", "doctor", "janitor", "chef", "surgeon"],     function(index, role) {
    for(var i = 0; i < maxNumberOfPairs; i++){
        var pairIdSubString = "attribute_" + i + "_" + role;
        pairsHash["attribute_" + i] = [pairIdSubString + "_night", pairIdSubString + "_day"];
    }
    container [role] = pairsHash;
});
```

If you run this you get a nice nested output inside `container` but when you look at each array in the hash you get a weird behaviour with the string produced.

Each one has the last role in each string like so:
"attribute_0_**surgeon**_night"

If you log out the variable `pairIdSubString` it correctly has the role in the string, but as soon as this is added to `pairHash` it just uses the last element in the `$.each` array.

I was able to fix it by moving `pairsHash` inside the `$.each` but outside the `for` loop.

Can anyone explain to my why the output was different after moving it inside the each?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, you previously had container[role] = pairsHash; outside of the $.each?

Comment: To be clear on one more thing even though it looks like you are accessing pairsHash like an array it's an object. All arrays are objects so they are also always passed by reference as well but both those variables are just objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually has to do with reference vs value. When its outside the each you are operating on the same object over and over so every time you set it to the container you are just setting a reference to the same object that is constantly changing. So every reference in container after the loop is the last state of the pairsHash because they all point to the same object.

When you put the pairsHash in the each it is reinitialized every time so they all point to different memory addresses. Not the same one since a new one is created every loop.

To further clarify all objects are just references to a memory address In JavaScript so in order to get new one you need to initialize or to pass by value to a function clone it.

Comment: Hit the nail on the head. Some people run into this problem with the for variable i too :)